# How to create a container with two shadows in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, shadow

I've tried to create a Column with two container and each one with a different boxShadow, but the bottom one gets on top of the other one. I've also tried to use the offset property to move the shadows a bit, but I don't really get the "two shadows" effect.

[image]

The code is the following:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 65,
      width: 45,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    blurRadius: 4,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    offset: Offset(0, -3),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    blurRadius: 4,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                  ),
                ],
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Stack to overlap the white Container:

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 100,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    offset: Offset(0, -3),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: the problem is the top shadow in the second container @LOfG

Answer (score 1):

<s>BoxShadow has a padding property to do something similar, but i don't know if it might suit your needs . Check [the PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/28948) , maybe you should be adding 2 shadows to the root containers. I'm not on my pc right now ,and codepen doesn't support padding in BoxShadows so i can't provide a working example ;-; Container( height: 65, width: 45, child:</s>

That PR seems to not have been merged. A shame. I've been trying to get this working by expanding the default [BoxDecoration](https://github.com/ivk1800/flutter/blob/70a965b5b2c94205ffaa29ba82afa4851e4bb8c5/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_decoration.dart) class, but the flutter team has decided to make the [BoxDecorationPainter](https://github.com/ivk1800/flutter/blob/70a965b5b2c94205ffaa29ba82afa4851e4bb8c5/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_decoration.dart#L336) class private... so the only way is to make a whole BoxDecoration from scratch and that's not good because the code is not maintainable anymore.

For performance reasons i would use a CustomPainter, however since LOfG has provided a solution that works you should use that unless you run into performance problems ;)

Comment: I'm in the stable channel 1.20 and my boxShadow don't have a padding property.If I use 2 shadows in the same container, one gets on top of the other too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add another shadow to the list of shadows ?

Like this :

```
class TwoShadows extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 65,
      width: 45,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow:  [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            blurRadius: 4,
            spreadRadius: 1,
            offset: Offset(0, -3),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(0.7),
                    blurRadius: 4,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    offset: Offset(0, 4),
                  ),
        ],
        borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that aproach is that the second one get on top of the first one, I saw that you used opacity, gonna try that.

Comment: I see. Do you have any image of the proper result you want to get ?

Comment: I think the answer from @LOfg is the best one (that's the result i wan't to get), but I don't know if using a stack is a little bit of an overkill.